# What is the procedure for reopening a question marked as duplicate?

Tags: support

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129702/12558) has been closed as a duplicate. I wish to suggest that the main issue has been missed when it was closed. How do I go about getting it opened? I have searched but not found the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those with more than 3000 [*reputation*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) points (such as you) have the [Cast Close and Reopen Votes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) [*privilege*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).  Use this to vote to reopen the post and it will be added to the [review queue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/review) for other members to affirm or contravene.

If one does not have the *reputation* required or one feels that the review process has failed you may [flag](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the post for moderator attention.  Please be sparing in the use of this feature however as it should be used in cases that are exceptional in some way rather than as a matter of course.

If you feel strongly that neither route described above has produced a fair outcome you can post a question here on meta which has (the potential for) the eyes of the entire community on it.

Comment: Thanks. I have worked through the above reopened the post and added my answer.  It all seemed straightforward.

Comment: @Hugh. You might also leave a comment saying why you want the question to be re-opened. This may encourage others to support you with their re-open votes.

Comment: I would be happy to do that. However, as soon as I went there and clicked on the closed question it reopened and disappeared from the reopen list. This surprised me. I have now been able add an answer to the original question. Has something strange happened? I expected to have to convince someone.

Comment: @Hugh according to the [revision history](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/129702/revisions) for that post it appears that by the time you voted four other members had already voted to reopen, perhaps as a result of this Meta question.  The fifth vote was binding and the post was immediately reopened.

Comment: That explains it. Where do you find the revision history of a post? I am learning much about SE today.

Comment: @Hugh Bottom-center of that post is a line "edited 15 hours ago"  -- that text is a link that takes you to the revision history.

Comment: Thanks. Obvious now you point it out. I didn't realise it was a link.